# Sony Vaio brightness [Radeon 7500M/7600M Series] in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: brightness, vaio, sony

I bought a Sony Vaio with windows 7 preinstalled. Now I have a lot of problem installing Ubuntu, but I was able to install Ubuntu, but now the brightness doesn't work as needed.

With `lspci` I get:

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames [Radeon 7500M/7600M Series]
```

How can I solve this ?

Too much light is hurting my eyes, the brightness is at maximum level and I use the computer to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing xbacklight using apt-get (`sudo apt-get install xbacklight`). Then try this from the terminal, too: `xbacklight -20`. If brightness is decreased when running this last command, then this solution might work for you: [How to use xbacklight with brightness keys in a VAIO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/273045/how-to-use-xbacklight-with-brightness-keys-in-a-vaio) (you'll need to edit some of the paths inside the script).

Hope it helps.

Comment: It not work for me! How can I installed drivers to Radeon 7500M ? Thanks in advance

Comment: In 12.04 I used "Additional drivers" (run it from the Ubuntu dash) to install the one corresponding to my video card (it's not a Radeon). In later Ubuntu versions, this option has changed place. ---- Sorry for answering late, I didn't get an email notification.